# Browserify loaded with JqueryUI not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, gulp, browserify

I'm having problems using Browserify to load Jquery-UI.

The node modules for jquery and jquery-ui are loading fine with no issues. Only when I try to require them into a bundle using browserify, and load JqueryUI datepicker I get the following javascript error in the browser:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).datepicker is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

The `app.js` contains the following:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');
```

I'm also using gulp and laravel-elixer and my `package.json` contains:

```
{
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
     "production": "gulp --production",
     "dev": "gulp watch",
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "gulp": "^3.9.1",
     "jquery": "^3.1.0",
     "jquery-ui": "^1.12.0",
     "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0"
   }
}
```

The `gulpfile.js` contains:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.browserify('app.js');
    mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong? thanks

Comment: I have same error. Have you found any answers to your question?

Comment: Nope so I switched to using webpack for bundling javascript and haven't had any issues so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you are using jQuery-UI 1.12.
Browserify is incompatible with the new version.
The official upgrade page says:

> If you're using browserify: The UMD headers we have aren't supported by browserify natively, and the deamdify plugin has a blocking bug. If you depend on that combination, please help fix that bug!

https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/

I haven't tried it myself but you may be able to make it work by requiring individual widget

> var autocomplete = require( "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete" );

Comment: Thanks for that. I was able to get it to work by requiring all the dependencies listed in the array as the first parameter of the define function (at the top of the particular widget's file). For example, draggable has `define(['jQuery', './mouse', '../data', etc.], factory)` so I do: `require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse'); require('jquery-ui/ui/data'); etc.` and it seems to work. There is probably (hopefully) a better way, but for now, this works.